# Subversion to TFS 2010 RTM migration with timestamps

Tags: svn, migration, tfs-migration

Question is simple, if one needs to migrate subversion repository to TFS 2010 RTM what is the best tool to use.

I have found http://www.timelymigration.com/ and looks good but after contacting them I found out that during the migration timestamps on the changesets are lost. All timestamps are set to date of migration and real timestamps are stored in the comment of the changeset.

How to migrate from SVN to TFS 2010 RTM and keep the timestamps ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only other option is [Kyrosoft SVN-2-TFS2008](http://www.kyrosoft.com/products/index2.html), but I'm not sure they support TFS 2010 or timestamps. As far as I know there are only these two companies that offer SVN to TFS migration :(

Answer (score 2):

TFS does not currently allow the timestamps to be set when migrating changes. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2008/09/17/migration-toolkit-and-tfs-to-tfs-updates.aspx has more information, with the one of the key parts being:

"The core issue is with version control and stems from the fact that we have a single monotonically increasing changeset number that updates anytime any checkin in performed.  There is a direct correlation between the changeset number and the time that an operation occurred.  An invariant of the system is that if one changeset number is greater than another, then its date/time is also greater."

This discourages going into the TFS database and manually changing timestamps because there may be adverse side effects.